# ObjectMapper deserializing set all fields = NULL

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have superclass:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class AbstractDto {

    @NotNull
    protected String num;
}
```

And subclass:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SomeDto extends AbstractDto {

    @NotNull
    private Long id;
}
```

When I serialize it, all is ok:

```
{"num":"5600511164","id":22}
```

But when I try to deserialize, I get all fields as null in `SomeDto`.

I use this configuration

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper (Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
 return builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
}
```

I think problem is in use superclass, but I don't know how to fix it. Without superclass always work fine.

UPD.
Serialize like this:

```
protected String marshall(Object message) throws JsonProcessingException {
  return this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message);
}
```

Deserialize like this:

```
protected T unmarshall(byte[] body) throws IOException {
  return objectMapper.readValue(body, resolveType());
}
```

`resolveType()` return me `SomeDto.class`

UPD. Solved.
Problem was in body, it's not only `{"num":"5600511164","id":22}`, it contains another info.

Comment: Can you show the code where you deserialize it?

Comment: I updated post.

Comment: Have you tried using `ObjectMapper` directly? Because this works just fine: `new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"num\":\"5600511164\",\"id\":22}", SomeDto.class)` --- Maybe `resolveType()` returns the wrong type?

Comment: Unfortunately, the configuration of `ObjectMapper` is taken from the dependency (and methods `marshall` and `unmarshall` too). However, in the debug I see my class - `SomeDto.class` in return from `resolveType()`

Comment: If I remove `AbstractDto` and add `num` in `SomeDto.class`, it works fine

Comment: And if I try override `resolveType()` and return `SomeDto.class`, it isn't work, all fields are null